# Installing Qt Creator 3.1.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: qt

I have found [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and [manual](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/06/install-qt-creator-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) method to install [Qt Creator 3.1.2](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2014/06/25/qt-5-3-1-released/) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Which one is more reliable (has less bugs once installed)? The manual method offers 64 bit installation. What if I install using the PPA method? Will the 64 bit version be installed into 64 bit Ubuntu? May I expect some problems if not? Which one updates itself with Ubuntu? Is GCC 4.9.1 supported?

I reckon that Qt Creator is somehow linked with KDE. Shall I expect some problems when using Qt Creator with Ubuntu intead of Kubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

1. The manual method links to a specific version of Qt Creator. Installing from a PPA would install whatever version it currently provides, and the Ubuntu SDK PPA offers updates - so it might be have some bug fixes (which may in turn create more bugs).
2. Installing using `apt`, which you would if you use a PPA, automatically selects the version for your architecture, so you should get 64-bit by default, unless you specifically call for 32-bit.
3. Well, a manually installed program updates itself only if the program supports it. So taking care of updates is easier with PPAs than manually installed apps, in general. However I do not know whether Qt Creator offers updates within the program.
4. `gcc-4.9` is yet to arrive in [Ubuntu 14.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=gcc-4.9&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any). The PPA supports whatever version is currently in the release it targets, which would `gcc-4.8.x`.
5. The converse - KDE is linked with Qt, because it is built on Qt. Qt Creator runs fine with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can install `qtcreator 3.1.1` in Ubuntu 14.04 with [`ppa:alexey-ivanov/qtcreator`](https://launchpad.net/~alexey-ivanov/+archive/ubuntu/qtcreator) repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexey-ivanov/qtcreator

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install qtcreator
```